# CSS Animation to rotate element 360 degress on it self

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need help!
Here is my [codepen](https://codepen.io/jipe974/pen/bGjOjOQ)

```
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Bebas+Neue&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<div class="container">
  <h1>Custom Cursor</h1>
  <div class="box">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
  <div class="btn">
    <span style="--i:1">J</span>
    <span style="--i:2">o</span>
    <span style="--i:3">u</span>
    <span style="--i:4">e</span>
    <span style="--i:5">r</span>
    <span style="--i:6"> </span>
    <span style="--i:7">l</span>
    <span style="--i:8">a</span>
    <span style="--i:9"> </span>
    <span style="--i:10">v</span>
    <span style="--i:11">i</span>
    <span style="--i:12">d</span>
    <span style="--i:13">é</span>
    <span style="--i:14">o</span>
    <span style="--i:15"> </span>
    <span style="--i:16">-</span>
    <span style="--i:17"> </span>
    <span style="--i:18">J</span>
    <span style="--i:19">o</span>
    <span style="--i:20">u</span>
    <span style="--i:21">e</span>
    <span style="--i:22">r</span>
    <span style="--i:23"> </span>
    <span style="--i:24">l</span>
    <span style="--i:25">a</span>
    <span style="--i:26"> </span>
    <span style="--i:27">v</span>
    <span style="--i:28">i</span>
    <span style="--i:29">d</span>
    <span style="--i:30">é</span>
    <span style="--i:31">o</span>
    <span style="--i:32"> </span>
    <span style="--i:33">-</span>
    <span style="--i:34"> </span>
    <span style="--i:35">J</span>
    <span style="--i:36">o</span>
    <span style="--i:37">u</span>
    <span style="--i:38">e</span>
    <span style="--i:39">r</span>
    <span style="--i:40"> </span>
    <span style="--i:41">l</span>
    <span style="--i:42">a</span>
    <span style="--i:43"> </span>
    <span style="--i:44">v</span>
    <span style="--i:45">i</span>
    <span style="--i:46">d</span>
    <span style="--i:47">é</span>
    <span style="--i:48">o</span>
    <span style="--i:49"> </span>
    <span style="--i:50">-</span>
    <span style="--i:51"> </span>
  </div>
  <div class="triangle"></div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
```

```
body {
  background: red;
  height: 100vh;
  font-family: Bebas neue;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
h1 {
  font-family: montserrat;
  font-size: 40px;
}
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: white;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.box {
  width: 800px;
  height: 450px;
  background-color: pink;
  border: 2px solid red;
  border-radius: 10px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.box:hover {
  cursor: none;
}
.block {
  display: block !important;
  opacity: 1 !important;
}

.btn {
  width: 138px;
  height: 138px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  animation: loading 6s linear infinite;
  opacity: 0;
}
.triangle {
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  border-top: 40px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 40px solid transparent;
  border-left: 60px solid white;
  transform: translateX(-25%) translateY(-50%);
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  pointer-events: none;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
.circle {
  border:1px solid white;
  width: 138px;
  height: 138px;
  border-radius: 50%;
 /*transform: translateX(-142.5%) translateY(-0.5%);*/
  transform: translateX(-45%) translateY(-50%);
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  pointer-events: none;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
.btn span {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform-origin: 0 120px ;
  transform: translateX(0%) translateY(0%) rotateZ(calc(var(--i) * 7.05deg)); /* 360 / nbr de lettre */
  color: white;
  position: fixed;
  pointer-events: none;
  top: 50px;
}
@keyframes loading {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(-360deg);
  }
}
```

```
var box = document.querySelector(".box");
var btn = document.querySelector(".btn");
var circle = document.querySelector(".circle");
var triangle = document.querySelector(".triangle");


document.addEventListener("mousemove", function (e) {
  var x = e.clientX;
  var y = e.clientY;
 //triangle.style.transform = `translate3d(calc(${e.clientX}px - 50%), calc(${e.clientY}px - 50%), 0)`;
  triangle.style.left = x + "px";
  triangle.style.top = y + "px";
});

document.addEventListener("mousemove", function (e) {
  var x = e.clientX;
  var y = e.clientY;
//  circle.style.transform = `translate3d(calc(${e.clientX}px - 50%), calc(${e.clientY}px - 50%), 0)`;
  circle.style.left = x + "px";
  circle.style.top = y + "px";
});
document.addEventListener("mousemove", function (e) {
  var x = e.clientX;
  var y = e.clientY;
 // btn.style.transform = `translate3d(calc(${e.clientX}px - 50%), calc(${e.clientY}px - 50%), 0)`;
  btn.style.left = x + "px";
  btn.style.top = y + "px";
});

box.addEventListener("mouseenter", () => {
  triangle.classList.add("block");
  circle.classList.add("block");
  btn.classList.add("block");
});
box.addEventListener("mouseleave", () => {
  triangle.classList.remove("block");
  circle.classList.remove("block");
  btn.classList.remove("block");
});
```

I want to be able to hide my cursor when I hover over a zone
and when I am on this zone (in the codepen this zone is the div .box)
I want to make a custom cursor appear.
The complexity comes from the fact that I want my triangle, circle and rounded text elements to be aligned at their centre. I also want the text to rotate on itself.

I think I'm not far off but the text turns with an offset
Can you help me?
thank you

Comment: You can keep wrestling with this, but a much more elegant method is to use SVG `textPath` which has [pretty good browser support](https://caniuse.com/?search=textPath). This separates the radial text from the parent container CSS and eliminates the need to wrap a `<span>` around every letter (nuts!). [Here's an example](https://codepen.io/Shaikat/pen/PapGpr?editors=1100). Then you just have to attach the parent container to your mouse cursor position, as you already do.

Comment: Thank you, I reworked my code but it does not work, can you help me please https://codepen.io/jipe974/pen/abjxoNy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://codepen.io/jipe974/pen/abjxoNy

I find the solution thanks all

```js
var box = document.querySelector(".box");
var innerbox = document.querySelector(".innerbox");
var box2 = document.querySelector(".box2");
var cursor = document.querySelector(".cursor");
var cursorinner = document.querySelector(".cursor2");
var circle = document.querySelector("#circle");
var triangle = document.querySelector("#triangle");

document.addEventListener("mousemove", function (e) {
  var x = e.clientX;
  var y = e.clientY;
  cursor.style.transform = `translate3d(calc(${e.clientX}px - 50%), calc(${e.clientY}px - 50%), 0)`;
  cursorinner.style.left = x + "px";
  cursorinner.style.top = y + "px";
  circle.style.left = x + "px";
  circle.style.top = y + "px";
  triangle.style.left = x + "px";
  triangle.style.top = y + "px";
});
document.addEventListener("mousedown", function () {
  cursorinner.classList.add("cursorinnerhover");
  circle.classList.add("click");
  triangle.classList.add("click");
});

document.addEventListener("mouseup", function () {
  cursorinner.classList.remove("cursorinnerhover");
  circle.classList.remove("click");
  triangle.classList.remove("click");
});

box.addEventListener("mouseenter", () => {
  cursor.classList.add("block");
  cursorinner.classList.add("block");
});
box.addEventListener("mouseleave", () => {
  cursor.classList.remove("block");
  cursorinner.classList.remove("block");
});

innerbox.addEventListener("mouseover", () => {
  cursor.classList.add("hover");
});
innerbox.addEventListener("mouseleave", () => {
  cursor.classList.remove("hover");
});

box2.addEventListener("mouseenter", () => {
  circle.classList.add("opacity");
  triangle.classList.add("opacity");
});
box2.addEventListener("mouseleave", () => {
  circle.classList.remove("opacity");
  triangle.classList.remove("opacity");
});
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat&display=swap");
body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  background:red;
}

h1 {
  font-family: montserrat;
  font-size: 40px;
}
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 1000px;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.innerbox {
  width: 500px;
  height: 350px;
  background-color: blue;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
.innerbox:hover {
  background-color: white;
}
.box {
  width: 800px;
  height: 450px;
  background-color: pink;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.box:hover, .box2:hover {
  cursor: none;
}
.box2 {
  width: 800px;
  height: 450px;
  background-color: aqua;
}
.cursor {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  transition: all 200ms ease-out;
  position: fixed;
  pointer-events: none;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  transform: translate(calc(-50% + 15px), -50%);
  display: none;
}
.cursor2 {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  opacity: 0.3;
  position: fixed;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: width 0.3s, height 0.3s, opacity 0.3s;
  display: none;
}
.hover {
  background-color: red;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
.cursorinnerhover {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
.block {
  display: block !important;
}
.opacity {
  opacity: 1 !important;
}
#circle {
  transform: translate(-49.9%, -4.5%);
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}
 #triangle {
  transform: translate(-1%, -0.7%);
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  fill: white;
}
#circle text {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Arial;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#circle circle {
  stroke: white;
  fill: none;
}
#circle svg {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 240px;

  -webkit-animation-name: rotate;
  -moz-animation-name: rotate;
  -ms-animation-name: rotate;
  -o-animation-name: rotate;
  animation-name: rotate;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 5s;
  -moz-animation-duration: 5s;
  -ms-animation-duration: 5s;
  -o-animation-duration: 5s;
  animation-duration: 5s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -ms-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -o-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
  -moz-animation-timing-function: linear;
  -ms-animation-timing-function: linear;
  -o-animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
} 

@-webkit-keyframes rotate {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0);
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes rotate {
  from {
    -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
  to {
    -moz-transform: rotate(0);
  }
}
@-ms-keyframes rotate {
  from {
    -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
  to {
    -ms-transform: rotate(0);
  }
}
@-o-keyframes rotate {
  from {
    -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
  to {
    -o-transform: rotate(0);
  }
}
@keyframes rotate {
  from {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(0);
  }
}
.click {
 fill: #E1E1E1!important;
 stroke: #E1E1E1!important;
 stroke-width:2;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>Custom Cursor</h1>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="innerbox">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
     <video class="box2" controls loop id="video-background" muted>
  <source src="https://media-us-westslateappcom.s3.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/madcowfilms/production/clips/514ebae1-ebbb-4477-addd-d52a30cd28c1-1280x720.2500.webm" type="video/webm">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="cursor"></div>
<div class="cursor2"></div>

<div id="circle">
  <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="300px" height="300px" viewBox="0 0 300 300" enable-background="new 0 0 300 300" xml:space="preserve">
    <defs>
      <path id="circlePath" d=" M 150, 150 m -60, 0 a 60,60 0 0,1 120,0 a 60,60 0 0,1 -120,0 " />
    </defs>
    <circle cx="150" cy="150" r="50" fill="none" />
    <g>
      <use xlink:href="#circlePath" fill="none" />
      <text fill="#fff">
        <textPath xlink:href="#circlePath">Jouer la vidéo - Jouer la vidéo -
          <textPath>
      </text>
    </g>
  </svg>
</div>
<div id="triangle">
  <svg>
    <polygon points="45,22.5 22.5,0 22.5,45"/>
  </svg>
</div>
```

but according to the screen I have the triangle that shifts

Answer (score 0):

look at the solution you can maybe apply.

1. To start you needs to create parent div `.cursor`, which contains all your elements like `.circle`, `.btn` and `.triangle`.

```html
<html lang="en">
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <h1>Custom Cursor</h1>
      <div class="box"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="cursor">
      <div class="circle"></div>
      <div class="btn">
        <!-- Your spans -->
      </div>
      <div class="triangle"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

2. This new div `.cursor` should contain new properties :

```css
/* Parent box, contain triangle, btn and circle */
.cursor {
position: absolute;
display: flex;

/* Center triangle in the middle */
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;

pointer-events: none;

opacity: 0;
}
```

3. Then you should update properties of childs css, because they will take opacity and display from the parent.

```css
/* Remove opacity and position absolute*/
.btn {
    width: 138px;
    height: 138px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 30px;
    animation: loading 6s linear infinite;
}

/* 
    Remove height, left, top, display (block by parent)
    change position to absolute
*/
.triangle {
    border-top: 40px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 40px solid transparent;
    border-left: 60px solid white;
    pointer-events: none;
    position: absolute;
}

/* 
    Remove left, top, display (block by parent)
    change position to absolute
*/
.circle {
    border: 1px solid white;
    width: 138px;
    height: 138px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    pointer-events: none;
    outline: 2px solid rgb(0, 255, 191);
    position: absolute;
}
```

4. Like all elements are in the div `.cursor`, now we will only act on this one.

```js
var box = document.querySelector(".box");

// Cursor box contain all child element, btn, circle, triangle
var cursor = document.querySelector(".cursor");

const halfSizeCircle = 138 / 2; // 69

box.addEventListener("mousemove", function (e) {
    // Get coordinate middle of the mouse inside div .box
    var [x, y] = [e.clientY - halfSizeCircle, e.clientX - halfSizeCircle];

    cursor.style.top = x + "px";
    cursor.style.left = y + "px";
});

// Remove class .block
box.addEventListener("mouseleave", () => cursor.classList.remove("block"));

// Add class .block
box.addEventListener("mouseenter", () => cursor.classList.add("block"));
```

Hope this solution will help you ‍♂️.

Comment: Hello 

I made the changes you advised.
They are relevant because it simplifies the code, however the text does not turn on center, and I still can not center it

Comment: I reworked my code but it does not work, can you help me please https://codepen.io/jipe974/pen/abjxoNy

Comment: Hi, i saw you find the solution well done. Don't forget to close question as resolved.